# MATLAB: converting string with custom defined symbolic function to symbolic function, and evaluate it

Tags: matlab

I have a string from a MATLAB form:

```
string = 'funcTwo(funcOne(a,funcTwo(b,a)),funcThree(a))'
```

and I have defined following functions as symbolic functions:

```
syms a b l
funcOne(a,b) = a*b - a^b
funcTwo(a,b) = a*b - b^b
funcThree(a) = 5+a*7
```

I want to evaluate this string by performing the defined symbolic functions, as:

```
result = funcTwo(funcOne(a,funcTwo(b,a)),funcThree(a))

result =

- (7*a + 5)*(a*(a^a - a*b) + a^(a*b - a^a)) - (7*a + 5)^(7*a + 5)
```

How I can to this with a string as input? I have tried using sym(), but it does not work what I want:

```
result=sym(string)

result =

funcTwo(funcOne(a, funcTwo(b, a)), funcThree(a))
```

Please, help.

Answer (score 0):

The easy way (as in "suicide is the easy way out") is using `eval`:

```
result=eval(string);
```

however, using `eval` is unsafe, generally considered bad practice, and should be avoided at all costs. Since your expression is given as a string, I'm not sure there's another way to evaluate it.

Which begs the question: why is it a string in the first place? Can't you avoid putting your command into a string (which is the hotbed of using `eval`)? Are you familiar with [anonymous functions](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html) and function handles?